# How to see git diff from very beginning to the HEAD?

Tags: git, graph, diff

I am using `git` to track changes in configuration files of third-party application. At the first moment I did initial commit and then was fitting settings of the application gradually. Now I have final good settings and committed them into `git`. I wish to see what I had changed.

How to accomplish this?

I did

```
git log --graph
```

or similar, but see all commits marked with long hexadecimal numbers. May I use them for `git diff`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the -p argument with git log to get all diffs for all commits:

```
git log --graph -p
```

If you want to see the complete diff from the first commit to HEAD you can do something like this:

```
git diff `git rev-list HEAD | tail -n 1` HEAD
```

Answer (score 5):

> How to see git diff from very beginning to the HEAD?

At the very beginning, there was nothing, so the diff between nothing and HEAD is in fact.. everything that is in HEAD.
If however you define beginning as "after first commit", then just use git diff with the id of the first commit. (`git diff 1234567..HEAD`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following commands

Changes between head and index.

```
git diff --staged
```

Changes between head and working files.

```
git diff HEAD
```

Changes between two commits

```
git diff $commit $ commit
```

Also have a look to the following and use as per requirement:

```
git log tag..branch
git log HEAD~10..
git log -10
git log -10 master@{yesterday}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this simple command below to get the list of all tracked files:

```
git ls-tree --name-status -r HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

The following bash command helped me find a change that went "missing" today. I knew I had added some code with 'allowPublicKeyRetrieval' in some commit, but I could not find it and it had seemingly disappeared from any branch I could see in bitbucket.

```bash
git log --all --graph -p | grep -C 10 --fixed-strings 'allowPublicKeyRetrieval'
```

It turns out that the problem was that I deleted the branch where I did this change, since I felt the rest of changes in there was "just an experiment". Luckily, in git, deleting a branch is not more destructive than deleting any tag, it does not delete any commits.

By using `git log --all` you can list absolutely all commits ever made on any branch (or no branch at all) in your repository. The other commands serve to list the diff for each commit and then textually search through it.

Of course, In general, instead of `'allowPublicKeyRetrieval'` you would put some text that you know you added or deleted in some commit that you are looking for.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).